Why do ML models learn probability distributions and why does it matter?
I'm aware that this question is quite silly, but I've done reading and coded NNs for quite a while now, studied backpropagation and so on.
However, I don't think I ever understood what is the probability distribution that NNs model ?
I do know that they are frequency v feature plots, but I why would learning the number of L shaped borders within a dataset help at all ?
Certainly I don't see linear regression learning any of that either (I looked for an extremely simple case to analyse.)
What is your conceptual explanation, if possible in simple terms? Can you refer me to any article for beginners in this sense?

Linear regression absolutely learns a probability distribution, albeit a very restricted one. I am not quite sure I understand what you mean by "learning probability distributions". Do you mean that they output full predictive densities for the outcome modeled, like linear regression per the link I give?

You could improve your question by carefully rephrasing, explaining, and getting rid of typos.

In ML courses, classification is frequently described as a fixed, known labelling (eg is this a picture of a chair or not?).
Sometimes the labelling really is deterministic ( eg we might define a rich person as anyone earning over 100,000USD per year)
This is not the view of statisticians.
The basic assumption is that the input is associated with the output stochastically - 30% of the time this set of inputs was associated with rain, and 70% with sun.
Going back to the visual classification example
There are a number of sources of uncertainty. For instance, multiple objects in the same image.
 Should we label a picture as 'dalmatian' or 'cherry', is it a picture of a convertible car or its grille? Multiple people will label the images differently.
Secondly, what the Neural network "sees" is not the same as what we see.  To take a very simplistic example, we summarise the image by eg the intensity histogram across the image, and then ask an ML model to classify the histogram as cat/dog/car etc. Clearly there is no fixed labelling of the histograms possible, there is not enough information, but we can output probabilities for each class(which may be bad - close to equal probability).
A convolutional neural network has different, more sophisticated features than a plain intensity histogram, but it's still guessing a class from some image feature statistics, so it outputs the probability that a given combination of features is associated with that label.

I find it problematic to use the example you've chosen where you shoehorn a multi-label problem into a multi-class framework. The fact is that the one photo has a cherries AND a dalmation.

I am not shoehorning.these are (IIRC) from imagenet - used for image classification tasks (not eg image segmentation). Its precisely my point that any realworld image (scraped from the internet) will have multiple objects in it. yet we label it as a single object class. see eg https://github.com/EliSchwartz/imagenet-sample-images/blob/master/gallery.md

If you want to make the argument that there is some probability of people identifying that one picture as being of a dalmation and some other probability of people identifying that picture of being of cherries (perhaps grapes can be in the mix, too), then I think that would make sense, but I do think that should be made explicit.

First, you don't have to think much about probability distributions. You have some values. You want to find the neural network parameters that get as close as possible to those values, measured by some notion of "close".
This is exactly what you're doing if you plot some data in Excel and hit add trendline. You just find the line that fits the data the best, according to the default notion of "best" that Microsoft set.
You hit add trendline without realizing that the notion of best corresponds to maximizing the log-likelihood of equal-variance, independent Gaussian conditional distributions, and you might not care as long as the line fits tightly to the points.
You can take that attitude in machine learning, and it might take you pretty far, yet it does not make an explicit mention of probability distributions.
But...
...it can be helpful to think in terms of probability theory. For instance, if you take the stance that the linear regression is not just minimizing the sum of squared residuals but is maximizing a Gaussian likelihood (equivalent to minimizing the sum of squared residuals), then we get an entire conditional distribution that is Gaussian with a mean at the predicted value and a variance derived from the residual variance. Then you can make reasonable claims beyond just the point estimate. Prediction intervals based on the entire Gaussian distribution can give you a sense of how much variability there might be in future observations. What is more useful, predicting a value of $5$ or predicting a value of $5$ that could reasonably be between $-1$ and $11?$ Only when you consider the entire distribution, not just the single prediction, can you get the latter.
When you fit a "classification" model by minimzing crossentropy loss, that crossentropy loss comes from the binomial or multinomial distribution and maximum likelihood estimation of the parameters. Now you have an interpretation of the predictions beyond just taking the category predicted with the highest value. These now represent the estimated probabilities of class membership.
Agresti's Foundations of Linear and Generalized Linear Models was where I got introduced to the idea of an entire distribution. The focus in that book is more on parameter inference than on prediction, but the first two or three chapters could be valuable reading. A textbook chapter on logistic regression should cover the idea of a conditional binomial or Bernoulli distribution, too, and then extending that notion is not such a leap once you get the idea of an entire conditional distribution instead of just a single prediction for a set of feature values.
The key point, however, is that, even though we observe some outcome for a given set of feature values, more than just that one outcome is possible.
A doctor sees a patient who has a cough. Maybe the patient has COVID. Maybe the patient has a regular cold. Maybe the patient swallowed a fly. That's a distribution on a sample space of $S = \left\{\text{COVID}, \text{Cold}, \text{Swallowed a Fly}\right\}$. Maybe it turns out that the patient has a regular cold, but it could have been COVID.
When you invest money, there are many possible returns on that investment. You hope to gain money, but you might lose money. That's a distribution on the possible returns, a sample space of $S=[-1, \infty)$ representing the fact that you could lose everything ($-1$) but there is no real limit to how much you could make. Maybe you wind up doubling your money using this investment, but you could have lost everything or tripled your money.
This post about simulating data for a logistic regression was quite helpful in getting me to understand the idea of an entire response distribution, too.
As far as why it matters that there is a whole distribution, there are a number of reasons.

We sometimes care about more than just a single point estimate. For instance, in the investing example, if there is a small chance of losing everything or losing more than the amount invested (e.g., short selling), you might think twice before making that investment, even if it has a positive expected return.

Even the point estimates mean something. For instance, when we minimize square loss, we are predicting the distribution mean. When we minimize absolute loss, we are predicting the distribution median. There are quantile loss functions to calculate distribution quantiles. Using another investing example, a predicted quantile $0.1$ (tenth percentile) less than $-1$ might tell you there is a decent chance of losing an enormous amount of money, a risk worth knowing when you make a decision about what to do with your life's savings. (This relates to what finance people call value at risk.)

The distributions can give an idea about how to fit the regression. For instance, if we have a binary outcome, we know the distribution is Bernoulli and can use Bernoulli maximum likelihood estimation to fit the model. This is what happens when you use binary crossentropy loss as your neural network loss function. PyTorch software, for instance, seems to call this loss "negative log-likelihood" as a slang that alludes to the equivalence with Bernoulli maximum likelihood estimation.



do you have any introduction to what you talk about ? i've studied linear algebra and calculus and derived the formula for regression (both using LA only and calculus only) without any statistical assumption, so i never thought there was the need to think about it.

Agresti's Foundations of Linear and Generalized Linear Models was where I got introduced to the idea of a conditional distribution. The focus in that book is more on parameter inference than on prediction, but the first two or three chapters could be valuable reading. A textbook chapter on logistic regression should cover the idea of a conditional binomial or Bernoulli distribution, too, and then extending that notion is not such a leap once you get the idea of an entire conditional distribution instead of just a single prediction for a set of feature values.

It really depends on what you are really modeling and your assumptions at the modeling phase. You can perform linear regression from different points of view:

Empirical Risk Minimization
Maximum Likelihood Estimation
Bayesian

In the first there isn't any probability involved at all (well, except for the underlying unknown probability distribution related to the data generation...).
I suggest that you read (at least) Chapter 8 of the freely available book Mathematics for Machine Learning, to better understand this.
